# A proof that entire function of order which is a fraction have infinitely many zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that it is the case, I can give examples like $cos(a\sqrt{z})$ or $\Xi(\sqrt{z})$ but I would like to see a strict proof and I don't know how to create one myself.

Comment: So what’s a fractional order?

Comment: I have changed my title. I mean an order of $\frac{1}{2}$ for example. basicaly any order less than 1. It may not necesarly be correct maybe not all of such functions have infinitely many zeros. I aksed my question based on few examples that I have seen.

Comment: Consider the Hadamard product. If an entire function of finite order has only finitely many zeros, its order is an integer (the degree of the polynomial in the exponent of the exponential factor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Picard's great theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), a trascendental entire function (i.e. not a polynomial) takes on any neighborhood of infinity all complex values an infinite number of times with at most one exception. An entire function of non integer order is not a polynomial, so that Piccard's theorem applies. But more is true in this case: there is no exception, that is, an entire function whose order is not an integer takes all complex values an infinite number of times. The proof is not straightforward, and is based on the relation between the order of the function and the order of convergence of its zeroes.

Comment: Of course I.dd not expect it to be trivial proof. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Just one more question, the theorem says that any function takes all the values infinitely many times in a nieghbourhood of a essential singularity. But, neither cos or Xi have any singularities as far as I am concerned.

Comment: $\infty$ is a singularity.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Can you please provide the source of the proof of  " _an entire function whose order is not an integer takes all complex values an infinite number of times without exception_" ?

Comment: @Topo The only reference I have at this moment is the book by A. Markushevich _Teoría de las funciones analíticas_, in spanish (translated from russian, of course). I do not know if there is an english translation. It is Theorem 2 in section 1.5 of chapter VII.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre $f$ and $f-a$ have the same order for any constant $a$. Therefore it is sufficient to show that $f$ has infinitely many zeros. Suppose that $f$ has finitely many zeros. Then dividing $f$ by a polynomial we can get an entire function with no zero. Then it is of the form $e^{g(z)}$ for some entire function $g$. By Hadamard's factorization theorem $g$ must be a polynomial, and the order of $e^g$ is exactly the degree of $g$, which is an integer...That contradicts our assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't know Spanish or Russian language and no soft copy of English version is available online. But I got the simple proof of that statement, which I've described in the above comment. Please verify it, whether it is correct or not !!